# django pagination doesn't work when click on the same page number

Tags: django, pagination

I am currently facing two issues

**Issue 1:**

the application developed in Django. I am able to navigate to Page 1 or Page 2 with no issues but
if suppose I am there on page 1 and click the same page 1 link URL will be ( 127.0.0.1:8000/query/="?page=1" ) I am getting the error for the page

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/query/%3D%22?page=1%22

on the console : 

Not Found: /query/="
[14/Oct/2020 17:46:10] "GET /query/=%22?page=1%22 HTTP/1.1" 404 3710
```

**Views**

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def query(request):
    print("ddd",request)
    tasks = Task.objects.all()

    form = TaskForm()

    if request.method =='POST':

        form=TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return redirect('/')

    products = Task.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(products, 5)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    page = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    NoOfProducts = Task.objects.count()

    try:
       xyz = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
         xyz = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
         xyz = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


    print("Price1", page_number)
    print("Price",NoOfProducts)

    if page.has_next():
        next_url = f'?page={page.next_page_number()}'
    else:
        next_url = ''

    if page.has_previous():
        prev_url = f'?page={page.previous_page_number()}'
    else:
        prev_url = ''

    print("next", next_url)
    print("prev", prev_url)




    context = {'tasks':products,'form':form,'Totalprice':Task.get_price_total,'page': page, 'next_page_url': next_url, 'prev_page_url': prev_url,
               'NoOfProducts': NoOfProducts}
    return render(request,'tasks/cart.html',context)
```

**urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
    #path('', views.index, name="list"),
    path('', views.query, name="query"),
    path('create/', views.createTask, name="create"),
    path('update_task/<str:pk>/', views.updateTask, name="update_task"),
    path('register/', views.registerPage,name="register"),
    path('login/', views.loginPage,name="login"),
#   path('login/', views.loginPage,name="login"),
    path('logout/', views.logoutUser,name="logout"),
    path('delete/<str:pk>/', views.deleteTask, name="delete"),
    path('query/', views.query, name="query"),
    path('products/', views.display, name="products"),
    path('dates/', views.showresults, name="search"),
    ]
```

2nd issue:

the Paginator orientation is not working on the page i have given the oreintation to " justify-content-end" but still it is displaying on the left of the page how to correct that ?

**Main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<style>
    .hello-msg{
    font-size: 18px;
    color:#fff;
    margin-right: 20px;
   }

</style>
<html>
    <head>
           <title>Ecom</title>

           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />

           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">

     </head>
     <body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'query' %}">Home</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'create' %}">Create <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'search' %}">Search <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
     </ul>
</div>
   <span class ="hello-msg">    Hello, {{request.user}} </span>
   <span><a class ="hello-msg" href="{% url 'logout'  %}">   Logout</a> </span>

</nav>


    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}

         {% endblock content %}

              <nav aria-label="Page Navigation Example">
                {%if page.paginator %}
                 <ul class="pagination justify-content-end">
                   {%if NoOfProducts > 6 %}
                    <li class="page-item {% if not prev_page_url %} disabled {% endif %} ">

                      <a class="page-link " href="{{ prev_page_url }}" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Previous</a>
                    </li>

                    {% for n in page.paginator.page_range %}

                       {% if page.number == n %}
                            <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page">
                               <a class="page-link" href=="?page={{n}}">{{n}}<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                            </li>

                       {% elif n > page.number|add:-3 and n < page.number|add:3  %}

                            <li class="page_item">
                              <a class="page-link" href ="?page={{n}}">{{n}}</a>

                           </li>
                       {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}

                    <li class="page-item {% if not next_page_url %} disabled {% endif %} ">
                      <a class="page-link" href="{{next_page_url}}">Next</a>
                    </li>
                   {% endif %}
                  </ul>
                {% endif %}
              </nav>

     </div>



     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/cart.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

iam passing the "  but still the pagination is loading on the left page. can somebody help me.

Comment: i tried to use it, but unable to understand the code  if i closely  look my code ,{{ (  <a class="page-link" href=="?page={{n}}">{{n}}<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> ) }}  this will get transformed to ( http://127.0.0.1:8000/query/="?page=1" )i am getting error in this line but it is defined still not able to understand what iam missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have `href==` in your template, but it should be `href=`.
2. Please try to add style to your HTML code:

```
...
<style>
.container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
</style>

    <div class="container">
    ...
```

Comment: Thankyou   Yes, href=  solve the issue, and the path query worked with the slash only, and any idea about the 2nd issue

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution., I implemented your code, then i got some overall different view, then realized the container was causing the issue the block content was tieing the template as a whole so, I separated the block content, now it perfectly worked